# How to write a C++ array printing loop that starts at a different point on each iteration?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a struct that has two member variables, each is an int.

```
struct trash
{
  int sector;
  int weight;
};
```

I have an array where each element contains one of these structs. All of the data is randomly generated within a set range. In this case, sectors are generated randomly from 1-7. Also, the array is size 15 in this instance. So each sector has a random number of weight variables associated with it. What I am trying to accomplish is printing out what piles belong to each sector. So the format should look like this

```
Sector 1
Pile 1: xxx
Pile 2: xxx
...
Sector 2
Pile 1: xxx
....
Sector 7
```

and so on if that makes sense

My attempt at this so far was to sort the array of structs by sector from least to greatest first and then print out the weight variable of each by iterating over the array using for loops. In a nutshell, I just want to print out the array in order after it is sorted by sector but break it up by sector. I can't for the life of me seem to figure out how to accomplish this in a compact, concise way. Below is the loop I have written now that doesnt quite work because the inner loop starts at the same point each time.

```
for(int i=0;i<NUM_SEC;i++)
  {
    cout<<"Sector "<<(i+1)<<endl;
    for(int j=0;j<num_piles[i];j++)
    { 
      cout<<"Pile "<<(j+1)<<": "<<data[j].weight<<endl;
      cout<<endl;
    }
  }
```

Any tips would be appreciated, I've already spent hours on just this small aspect of the program and its very frustrating.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: "Hours" is not a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to access not data[j], but data[j + previous_piles]. You could then do something like:

```
int previous_piles = 0;
for(int i=0;i<NUM_SEC;i++)
{
  cout<<"Sector "<<(i+1)<<endl;
  for(int j=0;j<num_piles[i];j++)
  { 
    cout<<"Pile "<<(j+1)<<": "<<data[j+previous_piles].weight<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
  }
  previous_piles += num_piles[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not keeping record of your progress!!

Look at the following code:

```
int last_pile = 0; // will keep track of the last printed index
for(int i=0;i<NUM_SEC;i++)
{
    cout<<"Sector "<<(i+1)<<endl;

    for( int j = 0; j < num_piles[i]; j++)
    { 
        cout << "Pile " << (j+1) << ": " << data[j+last_pile].weight << endl; // sum last_pile to j
    }

    // updated last printed index
    last_pile += num_piles[i];
    cout << endl; // empty line 'cause finihes with this sector
}
```

I created a new variable `last_pile` which will store the last visited index. Then, inside the loop, I add the value of this variable to the sub-index `j` so you always get the correct element from the array.

Please pay attention to the comment, I added useful information there.